# Kubespray: impossible to install k8s version v1.26.x on Openstack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubeadm

Using kubespray v2.22.0 to install k8s version v1.26.5 on Openstack, installation fails during kubeadm token creation
After checking kubelet log, I notice kubelet crashs with following error message: "command failed": err="failed to run kubelet: unknown cloud provider "openstack"

I have used kubespray v2.21.0 to install k8s v1.25.4 on openstack and succeed without any problem.

I have used same configuration files with kubespray v1.22.0 to install k8s v1.25.4 on openstack but it fails. I guess there is something to configure differently somewhere but I don't find what

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, solution is provided in this [page][1]

In former version, parameter cloud_provider was set to openstack
This value is not correct for k8s v1.26
cloud_povider has to be set to *external* and a new parameter external_cloud_provider has to be set to *openstack*

Sorry for disturbance
[1]: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/openstack.md